# Setting a minimun column width for WPF DataGrid when all its cells (rows) are empty

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, .net-3.5, wpftoolkit

I have a WPF datagrid which has some columns. Sometimes, depending on the case, when it is populated there are some columns which have no content (the entire column is empty for all the rows).

```
<Window x:Name="MyWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"> 

<Grid x:Name="outerGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<my:DataGrid  Grid.Row="1" Name="MyDataGrid"                         
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyListOfItems}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MySelectedItem}" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" 
              SelectionMode="Single" ColumnWidth="*" 
              SelectionChanged="dgEfectes_SelectionChanged"
              Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=outerGrid}">

</my:DataGrid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Note that the DataGrid's width is the same as Grid's widht that is around it.

So, regarding to these columns that are empty (without content) I would like to resize them to have a minimun width (for example, its minimum default width or one I specify) so then I can take advantage of it in order to make the rest of columns wider and avoid horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The way (most) content of a grid works, is that it will fill all available space.
Unless you have some extra styling or code somewhere you're not showing us then you don't need this bit of markup:

```
Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=outerGrid}"
```

You've not shown us any columns and you set autogenerate false, so that seems a bit odd.
Also, Datagrid is in the wpf net framework so I don't follow why you have my: in front of it unless this datagrid inherits from datagrid somehow.

On the face of it, the answer to your question seems simple.
A datagrid column has a MinWidth property, you can just set that.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

As it turns out, there's some more complicated criteria.

Let's assume you have a viewmodel for your window and that datagrid's itemssource is bound to a property on that.  Add another property. You can either make this a double and bind the column width to that or use a bool and a datatrigger to set width.  Either way. Use some linq to iterate your collection and check whether all the values are not null. Set the property on the basis of this.
You can use trueforall https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdxe4x4w(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think I have not explained well. When all the cell values of a column are empty how can I set fixed column width? By default MinWidth for column is set to 20, and in my case, when all the cells for the column are empty, the column width is the same as its header width and I do not want this, I want column width in this case to be less than the header width, to a custom fixed value.